# Finding a set of matrices that satisfy a list of non-commutative constraints?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Suppose the following constraints:

$$
X^2=x\\
Y^2=y\\
XY+YX=c
$$

where $X$ and $Y$ are square matrices, and where $x,y,c$ are elements of the complex. How do I find a matrix representation of $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: I think I can find trivial representation for all dimension. Could you tell me what do you find more precisely?

Comment: Try expanding $(X+Y)^2$ and $(X-Y)^2$

Comment: @ChoMedit These are the generators of a Clifford algebra $1/2(e_\mu e_\nu + e_\nu e_\mu) = g_{\mu\nu}$. I am looking for a $n\times n$ matrix representation, identically the smallest n which holds --- I would expect $2\times 2$ matrices.

Comment: @Andrei $(X+Y)^2=x+c+y$ and $(X-Y)^2=x-c+y$. What is the next hint?

Comment: Given a complex $a$, can you find the matrix $A$ such that $A^2=a$?

Comment: @Andrei Isn't that just the matrix representation of the square root of $a$?

Comment: Indeed it is. But then you can find the matrix representation of $\sqrt{x+c+y}$, which is X+Y, and similarly X-Y. Now add these two matrices together. What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $x,y,c,X,Y$ are $n\times n$ complex matrices and that the unknowns are $X,Y$.

If $x,y,c$ are generic (for example, randomly choose them) given matrices, then your system has no solutions except if you are particularly lucky.

Indeed, the equations $X^2=x,Y^2=y$ generically have $2^n$ solutions. Then the couple $(X,Y)$ can only take a finite number of values ($4^n$) and generically, these values ​​cannot be a solution of the last equation.